# Sum with sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Can anybody help me in solving the following sum $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(b\log n)}{b}$$I tried using the expansion of sine function but got stuck there.

Comment: Is there any context? Mathematica doesn't have an answer.

Comment: In order for a sum to converge, the general term must tend to $0$ as *n* tends towards infinity, which here simply isn't the case, unless you meant to write *n* instead of *b* in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't think that this converges. You can use the [Term Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) to conclude that it does not converge.